# If $u, v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ then $|u|^{p-1}|v| \in L^1$

Tags: integration, lp-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Why is it that if $u, v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ then $|u|^{p-1}|v| \in L^1$?

The context of this question is the computation of the Gateaux derivative of the functional 
$$
J(u) = \int_\Omega F(x, u(x))dx
$$
where $F(x, t) = \int_0^t f(x, s)ds $ and $f$ is such that there are constants $a, b > 0$ such that 
$$
|f(x, t)| \leq a + b|t|^{p-1},
$$
for $ 1 < p \leq 2^*$. Here, $\Omega$ is a smooth domain of $\Bbb{R}^N$, $N \geq 3$.

Comment: Do you mean $|u|\in L^p$? That's what $u\in W^{1,2}$ would give you.

Comment: Also, if $v$ is supposed to be a test function, why assume $v\in L^1$ and not something stronger? As is, for an $L^1$ function the only multiplication that'll land you back in $L^1$ is by functions in $L^\infty$ (this you can't assume of $u$, but you can improve $v$).

Comment: You are correct. Indeed, the hypothesis given are that both $u$ and $v$ belong to $H_0^1$, as I have edited in the question

Comment: @Jose27 your second comment makes me think that the afirmation is wrong. However, I have seen it in many books. I am so confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the revised assumptions the result is correct: Recall the generalized form of Holder's inequality that says if $1/r=1/p+1/q$ then 
$$
\| fg\|_r\leq \|f\|_p\| g\|_q.
$$
Use this with $f=|u|^{p-1}$ and $g=v$ and $q=2^*=2n/(n-2)$, $p=2_*=2n/(n+2)$.

It's easy to check that $|u|^{p-1}\in L^{2_*}$ if and only if $p\leq 2^*$.